# "this" becomes undefined after certain button click (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am trying to save the selected option once the radio button is clicked. It is working fine until I press one of the buttons I have in the following code

```
 {Object.keys(this.state.activeContent).map((key, index) =>              
        <input type="radio" name="key" value={key}
         checked={this.checkOption(this.state.activeContent[key].id)}
         onChange={() => this.saveKey_Index(this.state.activeContent[key].id, index)} />
  )}
        <button onClick={() => this.saveActive(this.state.activeContent)}>Save Active</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.runHTML("<html> <title> test </title> </html>")}>Play</button>
```

The "Play" button gives no error and I can then click from the active list the elements I want. But when I click on "save active" I cannot click on any of the items in my list I get the following error: 
https://ibb.co/hpJp48

Here are both of the functions:
Play:

```
runHTML(htmls) {
    console.log(htmls)
    this.setState({moved: true})
    var template = { htmlContent: this.state.htmlContent };
    return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template} />)
}
```

Save Active:

```
saveActive(list) {
    this.setState = ({ moved: true })
}
```

And the error I am getting is from:
saveKey_Index:

```
saveKey_Index(key, index) {
    this.setState({ savedKey: key })
    this.setState({ savedIndex: index })
}
```

And yes I have binded the saveActive and saveKey_Index (the error is from saveKey_Index apparently) 
   `this.saveKey_Index = this.saveKey_Index.bind(this)
        this.saveActive = this.saveActive.bind(this)`

Why am I getting error after saveActive button and not after play? I can setState in the play button even though it is not binded as well. Why is that?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your component's `setState()` function with this code:

```
saveActive(list) {
    this.setState = ({ moved: true })
}
```

There shouldn't be an `=` there, just

```
saveActive(list) {
    this.setState({ moved: true })
}
```